Deduplication based on other dataframe columns
I have pyspark df1 as
+----+
|name|
+----+
|   A|
|   B|
|   C|
|   D|
+----+

and df2 as
+------+------+
|name_a|name_b|
+------+------+
|     A|     B|
|     B|     A|
|     C|     A|
|     A|     C|
|     B|     C|
|     C|     B|

Now I want to keep or remove values in df1 based on values in df2.
Like A, B in df2 so keep A in df1 but remove B in df1.
The issue is if I get another pair C, A this will remove A this time even tho I decided to keep it when I encountered it in pair A, B.
How can I solve this in SQL or Pyspark?

what is your expected output?

what did you already try?

Here you can solve using below approach.
-- Assuming df1 and df2 are already created and populated
-- Execute the query to filter df1 based on df2
SELECT f.name

FROM (
    
SELECT name,
           SUM(action) AS final_action
    
FROM (
        
SELECT name_a AS name, 1 AS action
        
FROM df2
        UNION ALL
        
SELECT name_b AS name, -1 AS action
        FROM df2
    ) AS combined_actions
    GROUP BY name
) AS final_actions

JOIN df1 f ON f.name = final_actions.name
WHERE final_actions.final_action > 0;

We can try this with temp tables and CTEs as well.
